# Are there any alternatives to ngUpgrade for running angular and angularjs side-by-side, or a way to opt out of ngUpgrade's $digest triggers?

Tags: angularjs, angular, web-component, zonejs, ng-upgrade

I have a rather large angular.js 1.6 app that I would like to migrate to Angular, but using ngUpgrade causes way too many $digests to be triggered (i.e. every time `Zone.onMicrotaskEmpty` is fired). Unfortunately the app I am migrating is already not too great performance-wise, so every extra $digest is a pretty big deal. While I can mitigate this somewhat with `ngZone.runOutsideAngular()`, what I would really like is to totally disable the automatic triggering of $digests from the upgrade module, and just manually trigger them when necessary; since the app is composed of coarse-grained components which I will migrate one-by-one, there will be little need for a change in Angular to trigger a $digest in angular.js.

Here are a few of the *possible* solutions I am considering; are any of them more "standard" (or less risky / error prone) than the others?

- Use a locally modified version of ngUpgrade with the call to `rootScope.$digest()` removed
- Host upgraded Angular components in an iframe and use `postMessage()` for interaction with the app
- Host upgraded Angular components in a web component (have not yet investigated how communication would work in that case)
- Bootstrap both an angular.js and an Angular app from the same document, letting them both process their own directives/components on the page

**Update (8/23):** For now I am giving option 1 a try (locally modifying the upgrade js file); while I usually like to avoid doing such things, it seems like the safest bet so far.

Comment: Curious to know how this worked out for you?

Comment: It has worked out well; since my new Angular components are pretty self-contained (e.g. I don't have an Angular component hosting an Angular.JS directive hosting an Angular component, etc...) the lack of automatic `$digest` calls hasn't been a problem. And if/when I do need those calls, I'll just explicitly make the calls like one does when dealing with other changes outside of Angular.js (e.g. JQuery and the like). And the modification is only to a single line (the call to `rootScope.$digest`) so it is pretty straightforward.

Comment: David, did you invest any time in iframes approach (2)? Which module loading do you have in your AngularJs project? I have RequireJS and it is causing too many head-aches even running NG-1 and NG-5 side by side :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to bootstrap a Hybrid App:

1. [UpgradeModule](https://angular.io/api/upgrade/static/UpgradeModule) - bootstraps both the AngularJS (v1) and Angular (v6) frameworks in the Angular zone
2. [DowngradeModule](https://angular.io/api/upgrade/static/downgradeModule) - bootstraps AngularJS outside of the Angular zone and keeps the two change detection systems separate.

I have tried both ways. To avoid all issues with `$digest` and performance I recommend using `DowngradeModule`